# Problem with start project on a server with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

i have a project in local with node.js.
We create this project with "create react app".

This project have a particularity.

The project contains in turn the client / src / libraries / other two projects folder.

On the premises everything works correctly without problems, (it is started with npm start) to make it use webstorm.

The problem arises from when I want to start the server, if I have to start it on the server, obviously the command "npm start" is not good.

I went then under the client folder, and I did "npm run build", in the .env file I modified the "NODE_ENV =" in production.
But when I start the project on the server with the command npm run server (node ./bin/www) the project starts but has an error:

SyntaxError: expected expression, got '

Other info:

```
My Nodejs version:v10.10.0
my npm version: 6.4.1
We use Mysql DB and is on the same server.
The server is a ubuntu 16.04
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a shot in the dark but try removing the whitespace from `"NODE_ENV ="` to `"NODE_ENV="`. When defining a variable in a bash terminal whitespace does matter so this could be what's causing your SyntaxError?